# Will TCP protocol send data to network layer if client and server resides on same machine?

Tags: tcp

How will be the flow of data in OSI model if client and server resides on the same machine ? Will TCP pass down the segments to network layer ?

Comment: There is no OSI model in TCP/IP, and no TCP/IP model in OSI. It continues to astonish me that they are still teaching the OSI model. It has been obsolete for 30 years.

Comment: Just wanted to understand flow of data at network level when client and server resides on same machine. You can ignore models while answering